# Is it possible to have the selenium tests in the same project which I want to test on Jenkins?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jakarta-ee

I use Jenkins to test and build my Java-EE-maven application automatically. I have implemented the selenium UI tests but into another project.

The build flow:
1) Jenkins builds my Java-EE app and then deploy it to Tomcat.
2) Another task with selenium tests is triggered and runs the UI tests to check my deployed app.

Is it possible to include the Selenium tests into my Java-EE project? I would like to have only one project. Tasks on Jenkins could be two.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

The normal way of setting the test names is to end them with IT and use the maven-failsafe-plugin so that they run in the integration testing phase.

For more information about the maven-failsafe-plugin have a look [Here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Comment: And need I the two jobs of same project in Jenkins?

Comment: you would use `mvn verify` to run the integration tests and `mvn test` to run the unit tests (integration tests are run in the integration-test phase and not the test phase).

Comment: You can also use specific maven profiles to break things up even more, see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Yes, thank you. But still, I need two jobs in Jenkins on same project but different mvn commands, right?

Comment: `mvn clean verify` will run all phases up to and including verify.  So (assuming everything passes) this would build the project, run the unit tests, create a jar and stick it in your local maven repository, then use the created jar to run integration tests.

Comment: if you just run a `mvn clean test` it will only run phases up to and including test.  So you can have 2 jobs with different commands or one job with a single command, it's up to you.

Comment: I cant have one job with two commands, because in the post build phase in first job I have deploy .war to the tomcat (after build and unit tests). So I need two jobs, right?

Comment: I cant add another command for IT tests after deploying to tomcat, right? In first job...

Comment: you can add multiple steps to the same job in Jenkins, start off with a `mvn clean install` to create the war file, then add a step to deploy it to tomcat and then add a step to run the IT tests against a environment where the war has been deployed.

Comment: Or you can modify your POM to deploy the war file to tomcat in the pre-integration-test phase so that you don't need multiple steps in Jenkins.  t's all possible and there are lots of options